# Как на бутстрапе контейнер с содержимым сместить?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не совсем понимаю как лучше сместить контейнер с содержимым, чтобы оно за меню не уходило?

Comment: Где ваш контейнер вы подробнее объясните. А то вам виднее а мы (я) не понимаю.

Comment: Как я вижу все нормально

Comment: @Duoxx Мне нужно сместить контейнер правее. Бутстрап выравнивает контейнер по центру

Comment: Так где этот контейнер? покажите

Comment: Добавьте код сайта я кажется понял

Comment: Постарайтесь задавать более развернутые вопросы

Comment: Обновил картинку, по умолчанию контейнер выравнивается по центру, а мне нужно сместить правее, но так чтобы он корректно работал на моб устройствах

Comment: Насколько я понял, не надо смещать .container. Задайте ему вместо этого класс .container-fluid и уже внутри него размещайте и меню и остальной контент.